# Looping over arguments in bash array for docker commands?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, scripting

I seem to be stuck here. I'm attempting to write a bash function that starts `x` number of docker containers, wish an array that holds exposed ports for the given app. I don't want to loop over the array, just the commands, while referencing the array to get the value. The function looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a HOSTS=( ["app1"]="8002" 
["app2"]="8003" 
["app3"]="8008" 
["app4"]="8009" 
["app5"]="8004" 
["app6"]="8007" 
["app7"]="8006" )

start() {
  for app in "$@"; do
    if [ "docker ps|grep $app" == "$app" ]; then
      docker stop "$app"
    fi
    docker run -it --rm -d --network example_example \
    --workdir=/home/docker/app/src/projects/"$app" \
    --volume "${PWD}"/example:/home/docker/app/src/example \
    --volume "${PWD}"/projects:/home/docker/app/src/projects \
    --volume "${PWD}"/docker_etc/example:/etc/example  \
    --volume "${PWD}"/static:/home/docker/app/src/static \
    --name "$app" --hostname "$app" \
    --publish "${HOSTS["$app"]}":"${HOSTS["$app"]}" \
    example ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:"${HOSTS[$app]}";
    echo "$app"
   done
  }
```

And I want to pass arguments like so:

`./script.sh start app1 app2 app4`

Right now it isn't echoing the app so that points towards the for loop being declared incorrectly...could use some pointers on this.

Comment: Note that you don't need any of the backslashes in the `declare -a HOSTS=(…)` statement, whether you use multiple lines or not.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if [ "docker ps|grep $app" == "$app" ];
```

doesn't do what you want.  It looks like you mean to say:

```
if [ "$(docker ps | grep "$app")" == "$app" ];
```

but you could fail to detect two copies of the application running, and you aren't looking for the application as a word (so if you look for `rm` you might find `perform` running and think `rm` was running).

You should consider, therefore, using:

```
if docker ps | grep -w -q "$app"
then …
fi
```

This runs the `docker` command and pipes the result to `grep`, and reports on the exit status of `grep`.  The `-w` looks for a word containing the value of `"$app"`, but does so quietly (`-q`), so `grep` only reports success (exit status `0`) if it found at least one matching line or failure (non-zero exit status) otherwise.

Comment: I just tried giving it a go without the docker ps check to see if the for loop was running correctly and it, well, isn't. It may be an issue with looping over `$@` ...

Comment: You're into basic shell debugging.  Run: `bash -x ./script.sh start app1 app2 app4` and see what it does.  At the moment, you define a function `start()`, but never invoke it, so it may be that all you need is to add a line `start "$@"` at the end of the script.

Comment: Probably a better option still is to tell `docker ps` what you want to find; it will certainly be able to tell you whether an image with a particular name is running quite on its own.

Comment: @tripleee: If that's doable, then yes, you're right.  I was only using the facilities of `docker` that were used in the question.

Answer (score 2):

`docker ps -f` lets you conveniently check programmatically whether a particular image is running.

```
for app in "$@"; do
    if docker ps -q -f name="$app" | grep -q .; then
        docker stop "$app"
    :
```

Unfortunately, `docker ps` does not set its exit code (at least not in the versions I have available -- I think it has been fixed in some development version after 17.06 but I'm not sure) so we have to use an ugly pipe to `grep -q .` to check whether the command produced any output.  The `-q` flag just minimizes the amount of stuff it prints (it will print just the container ID instead of a bunch of headers and columnar output for each matching container).

Comment: I went looking for a bug report and couldn't find one, so I reported it: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35057